# This Response cannot Set Cookie in Heroku

Tags: heroku, routes

I don't understand why the following response is not able to set cookies.

It works in localhost.

[image: console preview]

Comment: In what browser? Without more info, I'd wager it's fallen victim to third-party cookie restrictions most of the major browsers have implemented in recent years.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's in Chrome.
I don't think it's a problem with third-party cookie, I'm working on the same domain.
In my opinion it's related to the proxy vegur on top of the container.

I tried to use the 'trust proxy' setting in Express without any result.

Comment: Is there a `Domain` portion to the Set-Cookie header? Is your URL scheme `https://`?

Comment: Thank you. No, I am not using the Domain portion, should I? Yes, I'm working with https, there are no problem with certificates.